# Exception in saving file on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-permissions

Earlier, I was using `KitKat` on my rooted device, I was able to create temporary files easily. But now I have installed `Marshmallow` on my Nexus 5, the same code is giving me an exception.

The relevant code is:

```
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

//      File repertoireStockage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
            file1 = File.createTempFile("RecordAudio",".mp4", storageDir);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("RecordAudio", "I/O Problem");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
```

Yes, I do have permissions outside the `application` tag in `Manifest.xml` file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Earlier, I used the commented line to get storage directory but now, both are not working. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

I have tried saving file after removing data cable, I still get the same exception.

Comment: please share your logcat !

Comment: You have to request Permission. Marshamallow has "Runtime Permission".
Read this slides to catch up on what's new
https://goo.gl/photos/9R6ss39caQHLyEmU6

Answer (score 0):

The OS brings a number of new features and it also has a built-in file manager, which may go unnoticed by many users.

Many third-party file managers allow users to rename files, create new folders, cut files and more. However, Android 6.0 Marshmallow's on-board file manager does not allow such actions.

> Be aware that the file paths they return will dynamically change when
>   the app is moved between internal and external storage devices. When
>   building file paths, it is strongly recommended that you always call
>   these APIs dynamically. Don’t use hardcoded file paths or persist
>   fully-qualified file paths that were built previously.

Link For reference

1) http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html

2) http://www.techtimes.com/articles/94044/20151012/android-6-0-marshmallow-has-a-built-in-file-manager-heres-how-to-access-it.htm